# My instagram data without oauth

Tags: php, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I am using doing a php project with Kohana but any leads that can help solve my problem is appreciated. I am trying to avoid the oauth process so I can continuously grab my photos and display them in my app. Every attempt I tried requires an access_token.

I tried using Request::factory() and pass my authorization credentials but it did not work.

I am wondering why I need an oauth and get an access token when I just want my own photos, likes, etc and nobody else.

Comment: I'd elaborate more if I had more time, and give a proper answer - but I suggest looking at getting an application token, and using that - that way you can automate the process without tying it to your other OAuth accounts.  You are probably looking to implement this as a 'two-legged' OAuth scenario with an application secret key that lives on your server.  I'd look into 'two-legged' OAuth and see if that model is more in line than the 'three-legged' scenario you are describing.

Comment: Also as a short answer to the 'why' - OAuth is a mechanism that is meant to keep third parties from overusing/exploiting public APIs.  OAuth attempts to provide a degree of verification involving interactions with APIs behind it.  Two-legged auth means you pass fewer tokens around, but ultimately your application requests a request token by handing off its credentials, and then you in turn pass that token with your actual request.  Three-legged involves user authorization to 'act on behalf' of the user tied to the OAuth token.  You probably will have to generate an application secret key.